# What IDE / compiler combination should a Linux user use to build Qt apps on Windows while avoiding MS Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, c, windows, qt, ide

I can't help it; I know many people will disagree, but I would *really* like to avoid Visual Studio as much as possible.

My ideal combination would be gcc + Netbeans. I already use those to code in Linux. But my issue is compatibility. For example, there is a [library](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/) that I want to use that is supposed to work for .NET and Java. Does this mean I need to use Visual Studio to access it?

Also, another thing I'm worried about is that Qt applications look like they can only be in C++. I can brush up on my C++ if I have to, but I prefer just plain C. Maybe I'm asking for too much here, but is there a compiler that will build apps fully compatible with Windows and Qt in C?

Comment: Qt is C++, you will need GTK if you want C (or some other library).

Comment: Do you realise that Visual Studio can be persuaded to build using compilers other than the bundled compiler from MS?  The IDE is excellent (and so is the compiler IMHO but for whatever reason you don't want to use it).  If you're interested, look in the help for "Custom Build Step".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an obvious answer, but there's the official development environment of Qt ; Qt Creator. Being written in Qt itself it's pretty much the same on Linux as on Windows.

The library you linked is a Java library. The only way this library works for .NET is via IKVM, a JVM implementation for .NET, so unless you have a compelling reason to use .NET components, I would avoid that route. I don't know of a simple way of working with Java code from native code, so I would also avoid writing your app in C or C++.

It sounds like the easiest route with maximum compatibility, with the stipulation that you must use [MXPJ](http://mpxj.sourceforge.net/) AND [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), is to use your chosen Java IDE + [Jambi](http://doc.trolltech.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/qtjambi-index.html), the Java binding for Qt.

If you are not fixed on the use of Qt as a widget library, since your chosen IDE is NetBeans, why not use [NetBeans Application Platform](http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html), or if your project is small and light, just use a Java widget library instead?

Comment: You know, I hadn't even considered Java (mostly because I've never written in Java in my life). However, that might be a good option. I guess the learning curve shouldn't be too bad, since I know C and C++ already. However, I'm not completely stuck with Qt. I just wanted something relatively easy and cross-platform at the same time, that's why I chose that.